# handle received sms using ionic framework

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Is there a way to handle received SMS using the ionic framework? Looking at the documentation of ngCordova, specifically $cordovaSms, it indicates a way to send an SMS but none for handling received SMS. What I want is a way to notify my app if there is an incoming SMS and process it immediately.

thanks

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I need to implement the same handler.

Answer (score 0):

I thin k if you add this Plugin it is possible

https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms

It has an "onSMSArrive" Event

Comment: Can you provide an implementation example?

Comment: there is an example implementation on github. https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms/blob/master/test/index.html