# How to handle an inbound SMS messages with Ionic

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm developing a hybrid mobile app with Ionic Framework.

I've encountered the following problem.
I need to implement the handler which will fire a refresh function in a controller, when the SMS is received. Also I need a possibility to fire this event only when SMS was received from a specific phone number, so I have to get the SMS info too.

I've read docs of [cordova-plugin-sms](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-sms). It has `onSMSArrive` event, but this plugin doesn't work with iOS, and I'm not sure that it's also working properly on Android.

Also I've found several questions by this topic:

1. This - [handle received sms using ionic framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737022/handle-received-sms-using-ionic-framework1), but it has no answers.
2. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573172/send-and-read-the-sms-content-sent-via-native-sms-app-cordova) one, which has the similar content.

I hope, that the community knows something new about this topic.

Is it possible to implement such SMS handler with Ionic for now?

By the way, my priority platform to develop is **iOS**.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot do this on iOS. An app has no access to the user's messages.